# What version of JasperReport should i use with Java8

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, migration

I'm currently migrating an app from Java 6 to Java 8 and have a little problem with a plugin used. When I'm building I have the following error:

```
Failed to resolve artifact.

Error transferring file: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
    PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
        unable to find valid certification path to requested target
            jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16

from the specified remote repositories:   
    Project (http://lmarccdkmaaf01.ptx.fr.sopra:10008/repository/Project),
    commons (http://lmarccdkmaaf01.ptx.fr.sopra:10008/repository/commons/),
    central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
    apacherepository (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2),
    jboss-ga-plugin-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all),
    jboss-ga-repository (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all),
    mvnrepository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact),
    Map (https://orion.agriculture/artifactory/Map),
    mvnrepository1 (http://central.maven.org/maven2),
    mvnrepository2 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
    cdk-map (http://lmarccdkmaaf01.ptx.fr.sopra:10008/repository/Map/)

Path to dependency:      
    1) org.codehaus.mojo:jasperreports-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2
    2) jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:1.2.0
    3) jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16
```

So according with what I see, I guess this error is related with the version of JasperReport I use.

In my pom I use:

`jasperreports-maven-plugin: 1.0-beta-2`

`net.sf.jasperreports: 6.2.0`

If you need anything else, I'm here. I don't know what to do, I tried to cross the latest version of my plugins but not results. So now I am begging for your help :)

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ
You probably have some CA certificates in your Java 6 installation and they should be copied into Java 8 installation. The problem is not related to jasperreports - maven is unable to get `jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16` artifact which is as a dependency to JasperReports.

Comment: Thanks but in Java 6 the dependances are downloaded perfectly without a problem. And when i search in my .m2 repository, the dependance is there ... So i don't know why maven is having a problem with it :/

Comment: And what happens when you try `mvn` command also with these parameters: `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true` ?